# What is the difference between running a code through the "console" and running it regularly?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm a beginner at Python and coding in general, and I've been primarily using the trinket interpreter to work out some of my scripts. I was just trying to get used to defining a function with if and elif lines alongside the return command.

[image: This is what the option looks like]

The code I'm trying to run is a pretty simple one, but when I run it regularly nothing shows up. However, when I run it through the console it
comes out fine. What am I doing wrong?

```py
def the_line(text):
  if text == ("just a boy"):
     phrase = ("I fly alone")
  elif text == "syndrome":
     phrase = ("darn you syndrome")
 return phrase

the_line("just a boy")
```

The first picture is what happens when I run it regularly and the second is through the console.
[image: This is what happens when I run it normally]

[image: This is what happens through the console]

Comment: Please don't add text and outputs as pictures. It will remain inaccessible to search engines and many users with disabilities, just to name two of the many drawbacks

Comment: @Neuron I didn't mean to make my post inaccessible, I was just showing the results I had. I'm not sure how else to show them apart from a picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very clearly explained in [Think Python's section 2.4](https://greenteapress.com/thinkpython2/html/thinkpython2003.html#sec19). It has everything to do with the [Read-Eval-Print-Loop (REPL)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) concept.

Briefly, the console is a REPL, so you see the output because it Prints what it Evaluated after Reading something (and then it prompts again for you to input something, that's the loop part). When you run the way you call "regularly", you are in what is called "script mode" (as in Think Python). Script mode simply Reads and Evaluates, there is not the Print-Loop part. A REPL is also called "interactive mode".

One could say that a REPL is very useful for prototyping and testing things out, but script mode is more useful for automation.

What you need to see the output would be like

```py
print(the_line("just a boy"))
```

for line number 9.

Answer (score 2):

In the console, when you run a statement but don't assign it to anything, the shell will print the resulting object. You call the function but don't save it in a variable, so it is displayed. The "console" in your IDE is also called a Read, Evaluate and Print Loop (REPL).

But your code really just discarded that return value. That's what you see in the first case, the returned object wasn't assigned to anything and the object was deleted. You could assign it to a variable and print, if you want to see it.

```
def the_line(text):
    if text == ("just a boy"):
        phrase = ("I fly alone")
    elif text == "syndrome":
        phrase = ("darn you syndrome")
   return phrase

foo = the_line("just a boy")
print(foo)
```

(As a side note, 4 spaces for indents please. We are not running out of spaces).

Comment: ah, apologies for the spacing. thanks for the explanation though:)